# how to login windows using pywinrm whithout password, If I can login the machine using my private key in pywinrm

Tags: python, linux, key, winrm

Is there any way to log in Windows using `pywinrm` without password? If I can login the machine using my private key in pywinrm instead of password.

I want to log in a Windows server form Linux, and I use `pywinrm` in python to do the work, but I need to provide the password, is there any way to log in without password?

`s = winrm.Session(hostIP,auth=(user,passWord), transport='ntlm')`

I want to find a way without password, such as use the private key store in my local Linux machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

No there is for this way. If you use Session you have to authorized . If it possible , telling the way of this is not ethichal movement for this web site.

Comment: I mean if I can login the server using my private key?